# Cloning Select2 with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I am having an issue with cloning a div with a select2 drop down.

When the first one is shown on the initial page load, the select2 works fine. When I click the button to clone it, the next select2 doesn't. It's like it's disabled and doesn't work.

My code is as follows;

```
<div class="input-main white_bg cloneneedsanalysis">
<div class="action-input clone-needs-analysis">
<div class="action-input-white-shorter">
<div class="inner-sub-title-less-padding">
<p>Audience Analysis</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="form-group">
<select class="select2 select2-multiple need_analysis_selector" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Choose ..." name="needs_analysis[]">
<option value="">-- Choose Audience Categories --</option>
<option value="536"> Finance -  - Cash collection</option>
<option value="537">IT -  - Comms IT</option>
<option value="538">Strategy -  - Strategy team 1</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="action-input-plus-needs-analysis">
<a href="#" class="clone_needs_analysis_button">
<img src="http://www.test.com/assets/images/plus.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div class="action-input-remove-needs-analysis">
<a href="#" class="remove_needs_anaylsis_button">
<img src="http://www.test.com/assets/images/minus.jpg"></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>


$(document).on('click', '.clone_needs_analysis_button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.clone-needs-analysis').clone().insertAfter('.cloneneedsanalysis:last');
    $(this).closest('.action-input-plus').hide();
    $(this).closest('.action-input-remove').removeClass('hidden');
    $('.select2').select2();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).closest('.clone-needs-analysis').clone(true, true)` instead of `$(this).closest('.clone-needs-analysis').clone()`.

You need to specify the `true, true` parameters to tell JQuery to also clone the attached events.

Check the documentation [**here**](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Comment: That copies OK, but the new cloned select2 selects the first drop down

Comment: @PeteNaylor Then why not use `$('.select2:last')` instead? :)

Comment: That then removes the select2 functionality from the first select2